# How to parse the attributes value inside {{}} (curly braces) inside a infobox

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Within Infobox at wikipedia some attributes values are also inside curly braces {{}}.. Some time they have lins also.. I need values inside the braces, which is displayed on wikipedia web page. 
I read these are templates also.. Can anyone give me some link or guide me how do I deal with it?

Comment: I agree with ShoeMaker: could you explain to us what exactly do you want? Because there are various ways how to “deal” with it, depending on that.

Comment: Well I need to extract infobox of Film, books and TV shows..  Like suppose there is a country , i just need  country value "UK" or US

Comment: I know dbpedia is there but I have already used it. Now m writing a script if the value is not found then it will be look at wikipedia page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double-curly-braces `{{}}` define a call to some kind of magic word, variable, parser function, or template.. Help can be found on [MediaWiki.org/.../Manual:Magic_words](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aMagic_words).  The little lines that look like `|` are called [pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) and are used to as separators that allow the wikicore parsing engine to define parameters that can be used with the magic word, variable, parser function, or template..

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help everyone who come across this very same issue.
Considering you will be parsing the infobox with PHP, you can use this:
http://www.mywiki.com/wiki/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=PAGE_TITLE_THAT_CONTAINS_AN_INFOBOX&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvgeneratexml=1

'rvgeneratexml' is being set to true (1), this will make the xml node `<rev>` generate an attribute "parsetree" containing the infobox information in XML format.

Then, in PHP, you can load the whole information (`<api>`everything including `<rev></api>`) with simpleXML:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

Then you can load the template's information by getting the "parsetree" attribute and loading the string with:

```
$template = simplexml_load_string($xml->query->pages->page->revisions->rev->attributes()->parsetree);
$template = $template->template; // If more than 1 template, check template[0], [1], etc
```

Then, by using the correct structure, you can access the elements with something like:

```
if ($template->part[0]->name='name')
    $film = $template->part[0]->value;
```

Then, `$film` will contain the film's name (`->name` is the parameter's name, and `->value` is its value).