# How can I export data from a raw wikipedia request?

Tags: php, html, wikipedia

I have this request http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?action=raw&title=Greece
and i am trying to get several information out of it: language, currency, long/lat etc.
Is there an easy way to get this data with php?

Comment: It appears regular expressions would work well so long as you are getting data only from the top part. ie not for the HTML parts.

Comment: You'll have to parse it yourself, but expect the page to change regularly and your parser to fail.

Comment: Read [How to parse Wikipedia XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839938/how-to-parse-wikipedia-xml-with-php)

Comment: so how would you do it? Is there a safe way?

Answer (score 1):

You could parse the file with PHP but i found a projekt which do it.

[PHP-Wikipedia-Syntax-Parser](https://github.com/donwilson/PHP-Wikipedia-Syntax-Parser)

there are some examples.

**Edit:**

For an URL open the URL with

```
$wikiString = file_get_contents('http://url.de');
```

then you have the result and you can work with it.

Comment: This seems like a solution, but can it process a url? Can I get dynamic results?(change greece to italy eg)