# Problems with Parsing

Tags: html, c, parsing, strtok, strsep

How do I parse an html/txt file using only strtok and/or strsep?

I'm trying that saves the text parts of a wikipedia article to a .txt file. The first part of my code allows me to download the article in html form. The thing I should do next is to parse that html file and save it as a txt file.

Comment: Hi, this is  unlikely to be possible using only strtok and/or strsep. Why the limitation?

Comment: Possibly related / useful: [How to parse Wikipedia XML with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4839938)

Comment: Googling `php parse Wikipedia` seems to give some good results, too

Comment: Maybe I could use something else other than strtok/strsep. I forgot to mention that I'm working with C.

Comment: Ah, I added the `c` tag. Wikipedia parsing solutions *should* exist in C, as well, but I can't find any at a quick glance.

Comment: I only need to extract the text from wikipedia without all the html tags. I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: [0] output every char until you... [1] find the first '<' [2] find the first '>' [3] goto 0 [4] ... and maybe add some handling for quotes...

Comment: how do I do that finding the first '<' and '>' and repeating that again for the next tags?

Comment: how do I prevent my code from copying the text inside the '<' and '>' tags?

Comment: You can use `strchr` for finding the first occurrences of `<` and `>`... and then loop through the next lines....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] and especially [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)  Note that you are expected to put some effort into your question.  You should show what you're trying (preferably as an SSCCE — [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) so that people can help you better.  You can use `strchr()` or `strspn()` or `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()` to help isolate parts of your strings.  You can use `printf("%*.*s", len, len, str);` to print exactly `len` bytes from the string `str`.  You can use `memmove()` too.